# wireless doesn't work when ethernet is configured with static ip

Tags: networking, freebsd

So, I have a FreeBSD host. Currently, its ethernet port is only connected to an ethernet switch (no DHCP server on that network) and the wifi is correctly configured and works.

---

Here's the `/etc/rc.conf` that works:

```
# Ethernet
ifconfig_re0="DHCP"
ifconfig_re0_ipv6="inet6 accept_rtadv"

# WiFi
wlans_ath0="wlan0"
ifconfig_wlan0="WPA DHCP"
```

With the corresponding `ifconfig`'s output (without the loopback):

```
re0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=8209b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,WOL_MAGIC,LINKSTATE>
        ether f8:0f:41:bf:05:49
        inet6 fe80::fa0f:41ff:febf:549%re0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
        inet 0.0.0.0 netmask 0xff000000 broadcast 255.255.255.255
        media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
        status: active
        nd6 options=23<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
wlan0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        ether b8:ee:65:4f:b9:c4
        inet 192.168.1.129 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
        groups: wlan
        ssid ThePromisedLan channel 6 (2437 MHz 11g ht/20) bssid b4:75:0e:9f:b4:9c
        regdomain 106 indoor ecm authmode WPA2/802.11i privacy ON
        deftxkey UNDEF TKIP 2:128-bit txpower 20 bmiss 7 scanvalid 60
        protmode CTS ampdulimit 64k ampdudensity 8 shortgi wme burst
        roaming MANUAL
        media: IEEE 802.11 Wireless Ethernet MCS mode 11ng
        status: associated
        nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
```

And the corresponding `netstat -r`'s output:

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
0.0.0.0/8          link#1             U           re0
localhost          link#2             UH          lo0
192.168.1.0/24     link#3             U         wlan0
192.168.1.129      link#3             UHS         lo0

Internet6:
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
::/96              localhost          UGRS        lo0
localhost          link#2             UH          lo0
::ffff:0.0.0.0/96  localhost          UGRS        lo0
fe80::/10          localhost          UGRS        lo0
fe80::%re0/64      link#1             U           re0
fe80::fa0f:41ff:fe link#1             UHS         lo0
fe80::%lo0/64      link#2             U           lo0
fe80::1%lo0        link#2             UHS         lo0
ff02::/16          localhost          UGRS        lo0
```

---

Here's the `/etc/rc.conf` that doesn't work:

But, as soon as I try to change the ethernet port to use a static IP address and reboot, the wifi stops working.

```
# Ethernet
ifconfig_re0="inet 10.10.10.1/24"

# WiFi
wlans_ath0="wlan0"
ifconfig_wlan0="WPA DHCP"
```

With the corresponding `ifconfig`'s output:

```
re0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=8209b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,WOL_MAGIC,LINKSTATE>
        ether f8:0f:41:bf:05:49
        inet 10.10.10.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.10.10.255
        media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
        status: active
        nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
wlan0: flags=8c43<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,OACTIVE,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        ether b8:ee:65:4f:b9:c4
        groups: wlan
        ssid "" channel 11 (2462 MHz 11g)
        regdomain 106 indoor ecm authmode WPA1+WPA2/802.11i privacy MIXED
        deftxkey UNDEF txpower 20 bmiss 7 scanvalid 60 protmode CTS wme burst
        roaming MANUAL bintval 0
        media: IEEE 802.11 Wireless Ethernet autoselect (autoselect)
        status: no carrier
        nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
```

And the corresponding `netstat -r`'s output:

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
10.10.10.0/24      link#1             U           re0
10.10.10.1         link#1             UHS         lo0
localhost          link#2             UH          lo0
192.168.1.0/24     link#3             U         wlan0
192.168.1.129      link#3             UHS         lo0

Internet6:
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
::/96              localhost          UGRS        lo0
localhost          link#2             UH          lo0
::ffff:0.0.0.0/96  localhost          UGRS        lo0
fe80::/10          localhost          UGRS        lo0
fe80::%re0/64      link#1             U           re0
fe80::fa0f:41ff:fe link#1             UHS         lo0
fe80::%lo0/64      link#2             U           lo0
fe80::1%lo0        link#2             UHS         lo0
ff02::/16          localhost          UGRS        lo0
```

---

I think the important difference is the `wlan0`'s status that is now "no carrier" after I changed the `re0` interface to use static IP.

Also, I was testing if my configuration was working after a reboot, which it didn't. But I also get the same result after changing the config and running `service netif restart`. Finally, if I boot with DHCP enabled on `re0` and switch to static IP, then run `service netif restart`, it doesn't work, but rebooting or running `/etc/netstart` works.

`pf` is disabled.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Stops working in what way? The question needs more info.

Comment: Show how you restart your network after changes. Show the output of `ifconfig` and `netstat -r`. Explain how you expect the packet to be routed.

Comment: When it works, wlan0's status in ifconfig is "associated". When it doesn't work, it's "no carrier". And of course, there's no IP address because because it doesn't even get to the point of asking for one.

Comment: @ClausAndersen I updated the question. What I expect is `wlan0` to be configured the same wether `re0` is configured to use DHCP or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news: **It works!**

Even better news: It works as **expected!!!**

The bad news: You **lie!!!** **;-)**

Or you have several issues...

I asked for additional information in a comment but you did not explain how you expect your packets to be routed. That might seem trivial to you but the question was actually meant to hint to a possible answer.

## Problem 1: WPA association

You must know of WPA and how to set it up as it works sometimes. We see it works as `ifconfig` says:

```
status: associated
```

If WPA is not working for some reason you would see:

```
status: no carrier
```

This magic incantation (`ifconfig_wlan0="WPA DHCP"`) in `/etc/rc.conf` instructs the networking subsystem to run [wpa_supplicant](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?wpa_supplicant) and then [dhclient](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dhclient) whenever operating on `wlan0`. DHCP (dhclient) will not be able to get an IP address unless we are associated (wpa_supplicant) to the wireless network.

You do not need to restart all interfaces. You can specify which one you want.

```
service netif restart wlan0
```

To debug this we need to run `wpa_supplicant` in `-d` debug mode with the correct `-c` config file:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -d -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

If you get the error that it is already running then shut down `wlan0` first. You can verify this with:

```
ps -ax | grep wpa
ps -ax | grep dhclient
```

You might think to do:

```
service netif stop wlan0
```

But this will remove the interface entirely. Instead simply bring it down (which will stop WPA supplicant and DHCP).

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
```

When you're done debugging enable it again with:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Another option would be to comment out `ifconfig_wlan0="WPA DHCP"` and restart the interface (or reboot). Then you can run wpa_supplicant in the foreground for debugging.

I do however not think you have a problem with this and this is your "lie" (we get back to this below). If you however do have problems with a slow and not quite stable interface then you might end up with something like this in `/etc/rc.conf`

```
ifconfig_wlan0="-ht WPA SYNCDHCP powersave"
```

I use this on my laptop with a `iwn` wireless adapter which otherwise have periodic problems associating.

`-ht` disables "High Throughput (HT)" see [ifconfig](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ifconfig). `SYNCDHCP` forces the startup to wait until dhclient return. This ensures that networking is ready before proceeding.

When we are sure WPA is properly working then we can go to town on `dhclient`. But I doubt the problem lies here.

## Problem 2: Routing

`netstat -4rn` shows us the routing table. You just claim that it "does not work". But you do nothing to illustrate what does not work and what you expected. I then need to make a boatload of assumptions.

So my assumptions are:

- Wireless networking is working in both cases
- You expect to be able to connect to the Internet via wireless.

And here comes the lie: In the second scenario you claim `status: no carrier` with no `inet` with `ifconfig` but then your `netstat -r` shows:

```
192.168.1.0/24     link#3             U         wlan0
192.168.1.129      link#3             UHS         lo0
```

So the routing stack knows of the network 192.168.1.0/24 on `wlan0` and you have an address (.129) on that network.

And if we look at the [netstat(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=netstat&sektion=1) flags:

```
H    RTF_HOST      Host entry (net otherwise)   
S    RTF_STATIC    Manually added
U    RTF_UP        Route usable
```

We are directly told that the route is usable. This does not match `ifconfig` with no `inet` line.

WPA and DHCP runs async in the background. You might have issued a `ifconfig` too soon. With that routing table your `ifconfig` will look different. Follow `/var/log/messages` to see what happens. And even worse if you use `service netif restart` when you add the IP address. This will then restart *all* network interfaces. You would then wait for dhclient to release the address and wpa_supplicant to disassociate. Then it will start up again - need to associate and then get a new address. This can take quite a while! If you simply set the IP for `re0` in `/etc/rc.conf` then only restart that interface with `service netif restart re0`.

As you are using [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) addresses for `re0` and you staticly assign 10.0.0.1 (typically the gateway) to that interface I guess this is a local network not connected to anything else. It could be. It would just be a sightly less common config.

In the first example you have it set for DHCP. No server is available so no address is set. We cannot route anything to that interface without an address. It is then "luck" that it is sent over the other interface which is available.

In the second example I then work on the assumption wireless networking is working and now you have defined 2 networks:

```
10.10.10.0/24
192.168.1.0/24
```

I am pretty sure you will be able to ping these addresses:

```
ping 127.0.0.1
ping 10.0.0.1
ping 192.168.1.129
ping 192.168.1.1
```

But you have not shown us how you test so we are left guessing. If any of them fails they give us valuable information for debugging.

If 127.0.0.1 is not working then you have a problem with your IP stack/firewall.
If 10.0.0.1 is not working it would most often be a firewall (but no pf or I assume iptables here) problem as this is our own address on our local network.
If we knew of another 10.0.0.x address (as we have a local /24) we could confirm it that network works.
The same with 192.168.1.129 - this is our own address and should work.
The really interesting one is the 192.168.1.1 which should be our router on the wireless network. If that works then we know we are able to connect with that network as well. In rare cases it could be configured to not respond to ping (ICMP ECHO) but that is rare. And my assumption is furthermore that this works.

Now let us try the fun part - connecting with the rest of the world. From what you have shown I will guess that you will get:

```
$ ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host
```

This would then be our smoking gun. We have determined that we can reach 10.0.0.0/24 and 192.168.1.0/24 as we know where these networks are. But how is your computer supposed to know where to send the rest?

If my now really high tower of assumptions is correct we simply need to know where we want to send all packets which are not to known local networks. We can add the default route to `/etc/rc.conf`

```
defaultrouter="192.168.1.1"
```

When you have set the default route you will notice that you have that listed as `default` under `Destination` in the routing table (`netstat -4rn`)

If you want you computer to act as a router for the 10.0.0.0/24 on your wired network so it can reach the Internet via the wireless you need this as well:

```
gateway_enable="YES"
```

You can read more on routing in the FreeBSD handbook [31.2. Gateways and Routes](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-routing.html)

## Problem 3: Your assumptions

You equate `netif` with `/etc/netstart`. Look inside `netstart` and see how simple it is - but how many things it does. As I assume your problem is routing related what you really need is:

```
# service netif restart
# service routing restart
```

## The real lesson

I spent a lot of time answering this question. I did not do it because this is an interesting question. But I wanted to show an effort because the OP made the effort to update the question.

This question is a very typical simple troubleshooting question we have all to many of here. I then wanted to show what steps I went through to answer this. Maybe I have been lucky and guessed correctly. But I hope it is clear how many assumptions and guesses I have needed. All of this could be avoided if the question had been handled more carefully.

The lessons you should take away:

- Do not ask of people to answer a question based on your own assumptions.
- Be clear in what works and do not work. State clearly how you test and what result you expect
- Show your precise troubeshooting steps.
- Do not cherry pick settings based on what you think is relevant (ie. /etc/rc.conf)

Notice how 2 different people asks for additional information. How little information you provided up front. And when updating you did not even provide all which is asked. The more time you spend on your question the more time people will spend answering.

Comment: I've read only half of your answer and it's already 1000x more helpful than any other comments/question I got. It explains how a few things work and explain how to debug certain other things. Thanks a lot!!

I did not have time to do more test yet. But I think the issue might actually be interferences and hell of a bad luck. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Again, great answer.

Comment: You assumed "You equate netif with /etc/netstart", but yes, I didn't know the exact difference. I'll look at the content o `/etc/netstart/`. :)